# Loading spinner div not rendered in time

Tags: javascript, html, css

**TL;DR:**

- `loadingSpinner` div toggled on before expensive code, toggled off after
- both `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` call `log()` which writes a message to `console.log()` and an element's `innerHTML`
- the `loadingSpinner` and log message in the DOM do not show up before the expensive code is done but the `console.log()` messages show up when they should

---

I have a reference to a div stored in `loadingSpinner` which is just a box that sits above all the other content that should indicate that the site is doing some work. I use these functions to toggle visibility of said div (`.hidden` is just `display: none;` in my CSS)

```js
function hideLoading() {
    log('hiding')
    loadingSpinner.style.display = 'none'
    //setTimeout(function (){loadingSpinner.style.display = 'none'}, 10)
    //window.getComputedStyle(loadingSpinner) // <-- TRIED FORCING REDRAW
    //if (!loadingSpinner.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        //loadingSpinner.classList.add('hidden')
    //}
}

function showLoading(text) {
    log('Showing')
    loadingSpinner.innerHTML = text
    loadingSpinner.style.display = 'block'
    //setTimeout(function (){loadingSpinner.style.display = 'block'}, 10)
    //window.getComputedStyle(loadingSpinner)
    //if (loadingSpinner.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        //loadingSpinner.classList.remove('hidden')
    //}
}

function log(s) {
    console.log(s)
    logDisplay.innerText = s
}
```

The commented out code are different things I've tried already. The show and hide functions themselves work fine. I can tell that the hide and show functions are called at the right time because of the calls to `log()`.

I have a few instances where the site does some expensive/long running tasks on the client of which nothing should be asynchronous, as far as I can tell (not sure about `Array.prototype.forEach()`). The Problem is that the `loadingSpinner` only shows up *after* the expensive task has completed and then `hideLoading()` hides it immediately. I did confirm this by adding a `setTimeout()` to `hideLoading()`.

```js
function updateDOM() {
    showLoading('Updating DOM...') // <--- SHOW

    log('Updating DOM') // <--- OTHER LOG MESSAGE

    codeContainer.innerHTML = '' // <--- start of long running task
    codes.forEach(code => {
        if (code.base64 === '') {
            backgroundQr.set({value: code.data})
            code.base64 = backgroundQr.toDataURL()
        }
        addCodeElement(codeContainer, code)
    });
    if (codes.length === 0) {
        editingId = -1
    } // <--- end of long running task

    hideLoading() // <--- HIDE
}
```

Console Log order is correct:

```
Showing
Updating DOM
hiding
```

But neither the text that `log()` writes to the `logDisplay`-Element nor the `loadingSpinner` itself show up when they should so I assume it is a rendering issue?

The issue is consistent in multiple places, not just the `updateDOM()` function.

Comment: Can you attach jsfiddle or anything else so that we can try and help you out. Thanks

Comment: Since the entire `updateDOM` function seems to be executing synchronous code, the browser is probably too busy executing code to render anything on the screen. Have you considered executing the expensive code asynchronously?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I did try putting the entire expensive code in it's own `setTimeout` as an easy way of making it asynch, that didn't help either.

Comment: Can you show us that in the question, or maybe link us to a jsfiddle? In theory, that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expensive code is being executed synchronously, the browser is too busy running it to find any time to render things to the DOM. One approach you can take is to execute expensive code asynchronously using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function to delay the expensive execution or send it to the end of the execution queue.

I've created the code snippet below that shows the approach, you'll need:

- Spinner handling functions
- Expensive executor function
- Asynchronous code runner
- Your main script that puts them all together

The snippet below contains two examples that you can toggle between, one performs a success execution, by running `main();`, the other a failure execution, by running `main(true);`.

```js
function showSpinner() {
    document.querySelector('#spinner').style.display = 'block';
}
function hideSpinner() {
    document.querySelector('#spinner').style.display = 'none';
}
function executeSuccess() { // runs something expensive that succeeds
    return 'data';
}
function executeFailure() { // runs something expensive that fails
    throw 'issue';
}
function promiseToRunAsync(executor, ...params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            try { resolve(executor(...params)); }
            catch (error) { reject(error); }
        }, 1000); // arbitrary time that you can set to anything including 0
    });
}
function main(failure = false) {
    showSpinner(); // show spinner
    promiseToRunAsync(failure ? executeFailure : executeSuccess) // execute anync
    .then((results) => {
        console.log('yay', results);
        document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = results;
        hideSpinner(); // hide spinner in case of success
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('oops', error);
        hideSpinner(); // hide spinner in case of failure
    });
    // ATTN code here will run before the spinner is hidden
}
main(); // executes the success scenario
// main(true); // executes the failure scenario
```

```css
#spinner {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="spinner">Spinning...</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**NOTE:** In the example here, I am adding a 1 second delay to the execution, just to illustrate what's happening, but you'll probably need to set your own wait time or no wait time at all.

Comment: That works, I don't understand why it causes an issue in the first place assuming all the JS runs synchronously. I'd think it would change the visibility of the spinner, **then** run the expensive code and block the thread. I guess it must be due to some optimization in the browser's rendering pipeline that made it decide not to render before starting to execute the expensive JS...

Comment: The DOM updating process is separate from the JS execution thread, so when the browser is too busy with the latter, it has no time to handle the former.

Comment: Great answer.  You can also add `hideSpinner();` to the `finally` clause to remove duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the code is asynchronous.
In the second you start your forEach loop, the code continues all the way to hideLoading while the forEach loop is still executing, therefore you will never see the loader because you call showLoading and hideLoading right after each other.

Try changing your code like this:

```
function updateDOM() {
    showLoading('Updating DOM...') // <--- SHOW

    log('Updating DOM') // <--- OTHER LOG MESSAGE

    codeContainer.innerHTML = '' // <--- start of long running task
    for (const code of codes) {
        if (code.base64 === '') {
            backgroundQr.set({value: code.data})
            code.base64 = backgroundQr.toDataURL()
        }
        addCodeElement(codeContainer, code)
    }
    if (codes.length === 0) {
        editingId = -1
    } // <--- end of long running task

    hideLoading() // <--- HIDE
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't seem to make a difference. The MDN page on forEach is very confusing to me so I'm still not sure if it is or isn't async. And the thing is that I do see the spinner when I add a timeout the `hideLoading()` but it only *starts* displaying *after* the expensive code ran so unless I'm interpreting something wrong, that can't be the issue.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. My suggestion was based on using an await while executing something on forEach - the two don't work together. But this is not the case here.